# Differences between 出発する and 出る

Tags: verbs, kanji-choice

Both mean "to leave" but when do you use one instead of another ? Does **出発する** implies "leaving and go on a trip" ? Or maybe is one more formal than the other ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

出発 refers specifically to *departure*.  出る, meanwhile, just generally means *to go out, to come out*, and could be used in reference to belly buttons, dresser drawers, stepping out into the yard, going onstage, or leaving a bathtub, among other potential contexts.  You'd never use 出発する for leaving the bathtub, unless you're being silly.  For heading out onto the town, or to do errands, etc., a better verb might be 出かける.